# Xamarin Forms iOS custom renderer for tabbed page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I have tabbed page in Xamarin Forms (iOS side). I need custom renderer for tabbed page - make first tab not scrollable (it could be shown as button or label), rest of tabs should be scrollable.
I think creators of Xamarin Forms tabbed page implemented tabs like a horizontal listview. I just want to put a button as first element on the left and then put that listview with tabs. When button is clicked, the new view is being opened. How to do that?

[image]

I am using Naxam Library to provide top tabbed page - this is extension to tabbed page (at iOS it is at bottom). I have tried to use custom renderer, but no breakpoint is hitted. I don's know why.

```
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Layout.xxx.iOS.CustomControlRenderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : Naxam.Controls.Platform.iOS.TopTabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "OnElementChanged");
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            AddButtonToTabbedPage();
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "ViewDidLoad");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "Dispose");
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "ViewDidAppear");
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "ViewDidDisappear");
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "ViewDidLayoutSubviews");
        }

        public override void DidMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
        {
            base.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);
            DependencyService.Get<IAlertHandler>().ShowCustomAlertVoid("", "DidMoveToParentViewController");
        }

        private void AddButtonToTabbedPage()
        {
            var btn = new UIButton();
            CAGradientLayer btnGradient = new CAGradientLayer();
            btnGradient.Frame = btn.Bounds;
            btnGradient.Colors = new CGColor[] { Color.Black.ToCGColor(), Color.White.ToCGColor() };
            btnGradient.Locations = new NSNumber[] { 0.0f, 0.1f };
            btn.Layer.AddSublayer(btnGradient);
            btn.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            btn.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Blue.ToCGColor();
            btn.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
            btn.Layer.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add noshifteffect to remove the default scrolling, its platform specific. You can add code to make 0th element not scrollable I believe

Comment: Can you share some codes you have tried so far? The screenshot in the question is on the Android device. In iOS, tabbar is always in the bottom and the pages can not scroll to next by default.

Comment: I have added code, that I tried. Screenshot comes from Android, but when using Naxam library - tabs are positioned at top in iOS. Right now tabbed page works the same like on Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the first tab, you can use `custom renderer` to achieve it. Change the `index<0` to `index<1` to fix the first tab in the method `GetPreviousViewController` and `GetNextViewController`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(myTopTabbedPage), typeof(myTopTabbedRenderer))]
namespace App12.iOS
{
    class myTopTabbedRenderer : TopTabbedRenderer, IUIPageViewControllerDataSource
    {

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }

        public new UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            var index = ViewControllers.IndexOf(referenceViewController) - 1;

            //in the source, it is if (index < 0) return null;
            //change here to if (index < 1) will fix the first tab


            if (index < 1) return null;

            return ViewControllers[index];
        }

        public new UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            var index = ViewControllers.IndexOf(referenceViewController) + 1;

            //in the source, it is if (index == ViewControllers.Count) return null;
            //change here to if (index == ViewControllers.Count || index == 1) will fix the first tab
            if (index == ViewControllers.Count || index == 1) return null;

            return ViewControllers[index];
        }
    }
}
```

And in your xamarin.forms project, use `myTopTabbedPage` to create tabs:

```
public class myTopTabbedPage : TopTabbedPage { 


}

var tabs = new myTopTabbedPage
{
    Title = "TopTabs",
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#9C27B0"),
    SwipeEnabled = true,
    BarIndicatorColor = Color.Green,
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
```

Try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have downloaded brand new project from Naxam top tabbed page github, then entered your solution, but it is not working as expected - 1st tab is not fixed. When debugging ViewDidLoad() is called once, but GetPreviousViewController is never called. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @YoungEddie I missed the code in GetNextViewController at first. Please see my edited answer. Also I have upload a sample project here : [tabbed-Page-sample](https://github.com/XfHua/tabbed-Page-sample). Note: I only write the custom renderer in the iOS project.

Comment: I have checked updated solution from your github on iOS simulator as well as on real device. I dont know why, but first tab is still not fixed.

Comment: @YoungEddie What do you mean by fixed? In my sample, the first tab is not allow to swipe to second tab.

Comment: I mean first tab is always visible on screen. For example if we have 10 tabs (only 5 is being displayed on the screen in the same moment). User scroll to tab number 10. Then on display he sees tab number: 1, 7,8,9,10. When scroll to tab number 5, he sees tabs: 1,3,4,5,6.

Comment: @YoungEddie Oh, I misunderstand it. Let me do some research and I will update you if I find a solution later.

Comment: @YoungEddie I tried again and find it seems impossible to fix the first like what you said by using Naxam library. You have to write a custom control by yourself to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have found custom tabbed page here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-mvvm-custom-tabbedpage/ I think that writing own custom page in XAML and implement it is the only available way to success

Comment: Yes, go ahead and write the custom tabbed page. If you meet any problem, you can open a new thread to ask:)